# LR Parser reduce/reduce (YACC, etc.)

Tags: parsing, yacc, lr-grammar

Assuming I have the following context-free grammar, in that particular order (for YACC):

- z → x
- z → z x

If I have an input of:

(z (z x

Will the parser reduce:

1. 'x' to 'z'
2. 'z x' to 'z'

I am thinking its no.2 but am not quite sure why. Thanks alot

edit: changed the input for clarification

Comment: If you have an input of 'z z x', your parser will object that z is an unknown symbol (because it is a rule, not a token).

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar is left-associative because it is left-recursive. Left associative means that the productions will be done greedily as the input is scanned from left to right. You always have a `z` which is extended to a longer `z` by scanning another `x` and reducing.

Regarding your question, you cannot have an input `z z x` because input consists of terminal symbols. Presumably `x` is a terminal symbol (otherwise the grammar is incomplete). `z` is clearly nonterminal.

You can think about a partial sentential form `z z x`.  Such a form cannot be generated by this grammar, however.

Starting with `z`, your next steps are to generate `x` (and thus finish) or to generate `z x`. The next possible steps after that is to replace the `z` in one of two ways: generate `x x` (and finish) or to generate `z x x`.

As you can see, the string `z z x` is not reachable by these rules.

Comment: Let me try rephrase the input then which may be a bit more helpful..

Let's assume the input is: (z (z x

Comment: That is a syntax error, since there is nothing about an open parenthesis in the grammar.

Comment: Correct. Lets assume then that the input is z x which should remove any ambiguity about associativeness, and if there is such ambiguity let's assume it is right-associative, i.e it looks at the right-most token first.

Comment: The input could not be z x because z is not a token. However, there could be a "sentential form" (partially reduced input) of that form. That would appear on the Yacc parser's stack. Input comes in as `x x`.  The first `x` is shifted, then reduced to `z`. Now you have `z x`. Since your grammar is left recursive, the reductions to `z` happen greedily.